# If $n$ is composite, then $((n-1)!)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod n$

Tags: number-theory

I don't understand how to relate it to Wilson's theorem. Wilson's theorem says that if a number is prime, then $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$.

How?

Comment: Don't relate it. If $n=ab$ with $a,b\neq1$ then $a,b<n-1$. Therefore $a|(n-1)!$ and $b|(n-1)!$.

Comment: @Asvin, that is not correct.  Consider $n=4$.

Comment: @Alamos Not only $a\mid (n-1)!$ and $b\mid (n-1)!$.

Comment: Actually it's just $n=4$.  For $n=9$, you have $3$ and $6$ dividing $8!$.

Comment: 4 is the only counterexample: see e. g. Benoit Cloitre's comment at https://oeis.org/A046022

Comment: @MichaelLugo The proof of that is a one-liner. $a\neq b$ is clear, and for $a^2|(a^2-1)!$ it is enough that $2a\leq a^2-1$, which is satisfied for $a\geq3$. There is no need for references.

Answer (score 4):

If $n$ is composite, $n=pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are lesser than $n$. And precisely for this reason, $p$ and $q$ are factors in $(n-1)!$.

If $p$ and $q$ can be chosen to be different, the statement is true even if $(n-1)!$ is not squared.